# Node.js and Backbone.marionette Initial View

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, marionette, passport.js

Currently, I have a *Node.js* app serving my static `/login` & `/index` HTML pages with my server side template language (***jade** in this case*). I would like to return data about the currently logged in user after successful authentication, so backbone can begin rendering the content.

For example, I have a `UserGroup` document in *Mongo* that stores information about the `User` and which group they belong to (*authorization info*).

With *Passport*, I can authenticate my user and redirect them to the main page.

```js
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate(
    'local',
    {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true
    }
  )
);
```

After a redirect, how can I send data about the user that backbone will pick up in the initial rendering of the `/` backbone route?

Will this be `res.send()` even though it wasn't backbone who initiated the first request or using sessions with meta data about the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an open request from the client. Try looking into socket.io to maintain a connection between the page and the server. If thats too much, try just making an AJAX request with backbone and have the server 'hold onto' the request until the login is successful and then send the response when it is ready. It'll be a challenge, though, to match ajax requests to login requests.

Comment: Without using socket.io, what would be wrong with having backbone build the login and logout request view. It just didn't sit well with me as those pages are anonymous views and i really don't want any backbone code initiating before authenticating a user

Comment: I have tried using backbone right from the start and it doesn't really work well, I end up with business logic on my client side to figure out who the user is and determine which View, Layout to render.

Answer (score 0):

I think the authenticated user will have a cookie associated with him. You could parse the cookie and construct a global user object upon app initialization.  Or, you could emit the user details in json format in a script tag on the page and use that to build the currentUser object. Im not sure if this is the best way to do this; I'm looking into it myself.  Would love to hear thoughts/feedback on this.